# Executing Gatling load tests from SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, spray, gatling

I wrote a small web service using Spray framework. I can run it using `sbt run` and then test it in the browser.

Now I wrote a load test using the Gatling framework.

```
package com.abhi

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class LoadTest extends Simulation {
   val httpConf = http
      .baseURL("http://localhost:8999")
      .acceptHeader("application/json")
      .doNotTrackHeader("1")
      .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
      .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
      .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")

   val scn = scenario("BasicSimulation")
      .exec(http("request_1")
      .get("/path1"))
      .pause(5)

   setUp(
      scn.inject(atOnceUsers(10))
   ).protocols(httpConf)
}
```

The test is located in folder `src/test/scala-2.11` and the spray code is in `src/main/scala-2.11`

When I run `sbt test` it just prints success without either running my web server or running the test defined above. it just prints success in 3 seconds and gets out.

How can I

1. ensure that when I do a `sbt test` the spray web application is
   started
2. the galing load test is run against the started server

Edit: I also tried `sbt test scenarios:BasicSimulation` and it threw the error

```
Not a valid key: BasicSimulation
[error] scenarios:BasicSimulation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the [Gatling sbt plugin](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/extensions/sbt_plugin.html) to trigger from sbt. Beware that it doesn't run in the default configuration but in [the `gatling` one](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.2/extensions/sbt_plugin.html#usage): `gatling:test`.

Comment: Thanks! I configured the plugin and I can do gating:test but it still doesn't launch the spray server. Can I make the gatling:test do a "run" as well? If I do a `sbt run gatling:test` it never comes out of run so never goes to gatling:test

Comment: Maybe an sbt expert can explain you how to do that. Then, you can run 2 different sbt processes. But still, from a load test perspective this doesn't make sense: you'll be testing on localhost and Gatling and app under test will share resources (CPU) so your results will be completely irrelevant.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I will open another question with the sbt tag which is more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Gatling has been written as a Scala application - it gets started as per a standard JVM app - you can see this in the [startup script `gatling.sh`](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-bundle/src/universal/bin/gatling.sh):

```
# Run Gatling
java $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$GATLING_CLASSPATH" io.gatling.app.Gatling "$@"
```

SBT doesn't "know" how to start a Gatling `Simulation` in the same way that it "knows" how to run a Specs2 `Specification`. Fortunately there appears to be a Gatling SBT plugin available that will do *exactly what you want* - check out the [demo project on GitHub](https://github.com/gatling/gatling-sbt-plugin-demo).